# Centering button vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, button, center

I have a big "Buy Now" button which is set at 100 width on my webpage. The text is centered on the X axis (horizontally) but it is not centered on the y axis (vertically). This is my class:

```
.col-boosting .btn-pay-rank {
height: 65px;
font-weight: bold;
background: #e06b38;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 7px 0 0 #c7511f;
text-align: center; 
line-height: 65px; }
```

Just for more info, here is a screenshot of the button.
https://gyazo.com/2d0b5fc4be72ba87c9cf73cd922d8ebe

Thanks.

Comment: Post more code - the problem is probably not in this section. Linking a jsfiddle would be the best way to show us this: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Consider using flexbox if the browser support works for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put "Buy Now" inside a

element:

```
<p>Buy Now</p>
```

Then align it:

```
p {margin:0 auto;vertical-align:middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button in a parent div and use this css :

```css
body {
  background: #f06d06;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
.parent div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    I'm a block-level element a fixed height and width, centered vertically within my parent.
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative solution from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#both-flexbox):

```css
body {
  background: #f06d06;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}
main {
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
main div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div>
    I'm a block-level-ish element of an unknown width and height, centered vertically within my parent.
  </div>

</main>
```